# Which framework is best for eWallet bitcoin development?

Tags: bitcoind, development, server, website-integration

What are the advantages/disadvantges of various web frameworks like Django, Ruby on Rails, Flask, etc when it comes to Bitcoin? Are some better at interfacing with the daemon than others? Do some implement security better or have holes that make them inappropriate for bitcoin development? Which is the best?

Comment: Note people who voted to close: Make it a habit to write a comment when you participate in closing a question so that the person who wrote it knows what was wrong about it. It is not necessarily obvious in this question.

Comment: Hi Kinnard, just wanted to let you know the reason this was closed is that it's really more of a programming question than a bitcoin question.  To be more precise, the users who can effectively answer this question are more likely to be found on a programming stack exchange than on this one.

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoin wallet development usually involves communicating with either bitcoind through HTTP JSON RPC, or otherwise with other Bitcoin Clients through the Bitcoin Protocol over TCP. On top of that, there are the usual requirements of authenticating users, securing data and so forth. All of those security issues are not Bitcoin specific, thus I think this question would be better asked elsewhere.